# How to check if a program uses Wayland or X11 in Linux?

Tags: linux, xorg, wayland

Is there a command in Linux that can tell whether a program uses Wayland, Xorg, or Xwayland?

Answer (score 8):

Not a command per se, but [*Sergey Bugaev* shared a cool trick](https://medium.com/@bugaevc/how-to-easily-determine-if-an-app-runs-on-xwayland-or-on-wayland-natively-8191b506ab9a):

> Launch *xeyes* and move mouse over a window. If the eyes are moving, it’s an XWayland window, otherwise it’s a native Wayland window.

[image: xeyes]

*xeyes* is typically pre-installed in most distros. Otherwise, it can be found in the `x11-apps` package or similar.

Comment: +1 Using xeyes for this is both funny *and* effective. If using Arch Linux, the package is [xorg-xeyes](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/xorg-xeyes/). See also [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1393618/how-can-i-tell-if-an-application-is-using-xwayland) related answer.

Answer (score 5):

I can provide a similar answer, but the tool should already be on your system.

You can use `xprop` which is most likely already available on your system. After you start the program using the terminal every X11 window will show you a crosshair, every Wayland window ignores your shoot for X11 properties.

Example on my system: on the left you can see Thunderbird drawing with X11 and left the Gnome Terminal drawing with native Wayland.

[image: See screenshot]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).